# Register a the location that a user has tapped on an image

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm very new to swift. I am attempting to register where a user has tapped on an image. I'm fine with using the global coordinate space if that's more efficient but would just like something flexible and dynamic.

The problem: I have an archery target (image), and I want to record via tap where the arrow hit.

Where I am currently: I have a view with the image. All tests I'm running are on the simulator in Xcode. Destination is the iPhone 12 Pro Max, but would like the code to eventually be flexible to work if I upgrade my phone, or (pie in the sky) if I decide I want to put it on the App Store.

Unexpected behavior #1: the image (of the target) starts at the top of the screen, but on the first click/tap, it moves down to the center of the screen. Would like it to start and remain in the center of the screen.

Unexpected behavior #2: when I attempt to populate the image for the hit location on the target, it is about 33 x units off to the right, and 126 y units low (are the units for the coordinates in pixels?) from where I actually clicked. In this image, I clicked on the center of the target. You can see where the red hit indicator is.

[image: Screenshot]

```swift
//
//  Practice.swift
//  ArrowDope
//

import SwiftUI

struct Practice: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var someQuiver : Quiver
    @State private var center = [181.0, 181.0]
    @State private var loc = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var showTap = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                Text("PRACTICE")
                ZStack {
                    Image("Target")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .onTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .global) { location in
                            print("WIDTH AND HEIGHT: (\(geo.size.width) \(geo.size.height))")
                            print("Tapped at \(location)")
                            loc = location
                            showTap = true
                        }
                    if showTap {
                        Image(systemName: "smallcircle.fill.circle")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .position(x: (loc.x-33.333333), y: (loc.y-126.666666)) // would like to not have to use these adjusted numbers, so that it works more dynamically. but this what's necessary to get the hit indicator to line up with where I tapped.
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI isn’t the best tool for this, SceneKit and SpriteKit are likely better options. SwiftUI is more for the Utility side of apps vs the game side.

Comment: @lorem will look into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach, using `VStack (alignment: .leading)` to align
the VStack, putting the `GeometryReader {...}` inside the ZStack,
and using `.local` coordinateSpace in `onTapGesture{...}`

Example code, works well for me:

```
struct Practice: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var someQuiver : Quiver
    @State private var loc = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var showTap = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {  // <-- here
            Text("PRACTICE")
            ZStack {
                GeometryReader { geo in  // <-- here
                    Image(systemName: "target")  // <-- for testing
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .onTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .local) { location in  // <-- here
                            loc = location
                            showTap = true
                        }
                    if showTap {
                        Image(systemName: "smallcircle.fill.circle")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .position(loc) // <-- here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a ton!